# NVD3 Date values are not correct

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to use nvd3 to display charts in my angular app.  I receive my date in the format of 2015-12-01T00:00:00. When I try to format this for display on the x-axis I always receive Jan 1, 1970 with a GMT offset.  Below are my chart options.  Where does the value passed in tickFormat come from or what am I doing wrong.

```
vm.options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'historicalBarChart',
        height: 450,
        margin : {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 65,
            left: 50
        },
        x: function (d) {
            return new Date(d.date).getTime();
        },
        y: function(d) {
            return d.data;
        },
        showValues: true,
        valueFormat: function(d){
            return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
        },
        duration: 100,
        xAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'X Axis',
            tickFormat: function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%b %y')(new Date(d));
            },
            rotateLabels: 30,
            showMaxMin: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
            axisLabelDistance: -10,
            tickFormat: function(d){
                return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            keyFormatter: function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d));
            }
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            scaleExtent: [1, 10],
            useFixedDomain: false,
            useNiceScale: false,
            horizontalOff: false,
            verticalOff: true,
            unzoomEventType: 'dblclick.zoom'
        }
    }
};
```

My data looks like the following.

```
[
    {
        data: 4.3722
        date: "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        data: 5.111
        date: "2015-02-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        data: 4.5758
        date: "2015-03-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        data: 4.9875
        date: "2015-04-01T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

**Additional Information**
It seems that there is something I am not setting when my data is returned from my angular service.  If I hard code the data in vm.data, the chart looks fine but when I switch to receiving data from my service all the dates are Dec 69.  Below is my call to the service and also my data object.

```
vm.averageZone = [];
var request = new requestObject();
shipmentService.getBasicChartData(request)
    .then(function(result) {
        vm.averageZone = result.data;
        //vm.data = [
        //    {
        //        "key": "Average",
        //        "bar": true,
        //        "values": vm.averageZone
        //    }
        //];
    });

vm.data = [
    {
        "key" : "Average" ,
        "bar": true,
        "values" : vm.averageZone
    }];
```

Is there something I am missing regarding my data and how it should be set up when returned from the service?

**Solution**
Below is what ended up working.  I removed the vm.data below this.

```
vm.averageZone = [];
var request = new requestObject();
shipmentService.getBasicChartData(request)
    .then(function(result) {
        vm.averageZone = result.data;
        vm.data = [
            {
                "key": "Average",
                "bar": true,
                "values": vm.averageZone
            }
        ];
    });
```

Comment: what does your data look like? can you put it in a plunker or add a snippet?

Comment: I have updated the question with a data sample.

Comment: The formatting is a little weird, but does [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/THY78CRr18XGzxWFloLx?p=preview) show what you're looking for? I don't know if you're getting a chart to render or not, but nvd3 expects your data to have a property called `values` (at the very least) to build your x domain and range from, so I reformatted your data object accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `xScale : d3.time.scale()`.

Your x value is returning a numerical value: `new Date(d.date).getTime();`, whereas the `d3.time.scale()` function expects a JavaScript Date object.

This plot should work fine with a linear scale, as you are representing your time data as milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. The conversion to a date format happens in your `tickFormat` function.

Comment: The dates are still all showing as Dec 69 after I removed xScale.

Comment: In xAxis:tickFormat, d is always 0, but when I look at the value returned in x, the date looks correct.  I must be having a complete disconnect on how this works.

Comment: I've done some more digging and the problem seems to be with something about my data.  It is being returned from an angular service.  If I hard-code the data, everything works fine.  I've updated my question with new information.

Comment: Hmm, are you able to post a jsfiddle or something similar which reproduces your problem?

Comment: I got it working.  If you look above in my question, I will show what I did.

Comment: Great to hear you got it working, thanks for sharing the solution.